# Error al leer el valor de una variable localstore por post en apache cordova, js, php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, apache-cordova

estoy haciendo una app donde quiero insertar en una base de datos una tipo publicación como facebook dos textos con una imagen con su correspondiente id según el usuario que lo traigo con LocalStorage, y es asi como recupero en javascript los valores

```
<script>
    recuperarId=localStorage.getItem("idUsuario");
    recuperarTipo=localStorage.getItem("idTipo");
    var titulo=$("#titulo").val();
    var contenido=$("#contenido").val();
    var insert = 'insert';
    var datos = "recuperarId="+recuperarId+"&titulo="+titulo+"&contenido="+contenido+"&insert="+insert;
    if($.trim(recuperarId).length>0 & $.trim(titulo).length>0 & $.trim(contenido).length>0) {
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"https://.../apk-publicar.php",
    data:datos,
    success:function(data){
    if(data=="Correcto"){
    //alert("Guardado Correctamente");
    }else if(data=="Error"){
    //alert("Error al insertar");
    }
    }
    });
    }
</script>
```

si me los manda solo que la variable recuperarID me lo trae con comilla doble en el php lo tengo asi

```
<?PHP
//permisos
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//conexion
include "apk-conection.php";
//variables por post

$recuperarId=$_POST['recuperarId'];
$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
$contenido=$_POST['contenido'];
$prbID=2797;
//fecha
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//nombre de la imagen
$nombreimg=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
//subirimagen
$new_image_name = urldecode($nombreimg).".jpg";
//ruta de donde se guarda
$rutaimg="../usuarios/img/".$recuperarId."/publicaciones/".$new_image_name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$rutaimg);   

if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
$sql="INSERT into publicaciones (id_usuario,titulo,mensaje,fecha,imagen)values($recuperarId,'$titulo','$contenido','$fecha','$rutaimg')
";
$ejecutar=$conexion->query($sql);
}
?>
```

a la hora de insertarlo si me lo inserta en la base de datos en un campo entero el recuperarId pero en el momento de crear la ruta para guardar tambien la imagen utilizando la misma variable no me lo acepta ya se hizo la carpeta ya tiene permisos lo decodifique con jsondecode($recuperarId), tambien con , intval,settype y no me hace nada sin embargo si le pongo una variable fija como $iD=3737; si lo incerta en la carpeta que tiene el id 3737 espero y me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema esta aquí:

```
 var datos = "recuperarId="+recuperarId+"&titulo="+titulo+"&contenido="+contenido+"&insert="+insert;
```

tu segundo recuperarId, si no me equivoco lo toma como una cadena en lugar del valor, tendrás que jugar con las comillas, puntos, comillas dobles , algo si me paso a mi en esta linea, no es lo mismo pero creo que se pretende pasar valores...

$("#Unidades"+number).on('change', function ()

la palabra number queda resaltada en negro en el código de mi IDE, y en un alert confirmo que si trae ese valor quedando por citar un ejemplo Unidades1, Unidades2 y así sucesivamente según la cantidad de modales que tenga disponibles para este propósito...
En tu caso seria asignar el valor que comentas espero te sirva mi comentario.

Comment: tambien lo pense pero ahorita el recuperarId le quite el localStorage y le puse un valor fijo tipo integer recuperarIdD=2797;  pero pasa lo mismo no me inserta la imagen en la ruta con ese id pero si inserta la ruta a la base de datos

Comment: orales entonces el problema es con el formato de la imagen, el tamaño o algo asi, hace muchos años hice un proyecto que nunca salio a la luz, pero lo que hacia era enviar PDF's a ciertas carpetas basado en la entrada y el usuario, el tema y contenido y en la bd añadía la ruta de dicho archivo, déjame ver si tengo todavía algo de ese trabajo en la oficina mañana lo  checo como le hacia, a lo mejor te sirve de algo.

Comment: No tendra que ver con los niveles de acceso: $rutaimg="../usuarios/img/".$recuperarId."/publicaciones/".$new_image_name; la direccion de la carpeta destino, que No  lo este encontrando aunque no te lo notifique.  ya que en usuarios tienes ../usuarios.. podria ser

Comment: gracias por la ayuda amigo pero no creo que sea eso,porque si sube la imagen a la ruta pero solo si desde la ruta le doy el valor fijo del id por ejemplo prbID=2795 pero si la traigo por post ya sea tipo string, int, array, json, asi ya no funciona si fuera el nivel de acceso ni siquiera eso podria hacer, Saludos